# Spring @ComponentScan in gradle subprojects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

When it is one gradle package with @Service definition and another package with dependency on this service, dependency is not satisfied.

I use root gradle project with two submodules, every with dependency on spring boot.

Root `settings.gradle`

```java
...
include ':shared'
include ':app'
```

Shared library `shared/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
}
```

Application `app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
}

mainClassName = 'com.example.app.App'
```

Application main `app/src/main/java/com/example/app/App.java`

```java
package com.example.app;

import com.example.shared.SharedService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.shared")
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var context = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
        var service = context.getBean(SharedService.class);
    }

}
```

Produces error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/shared/SharedService
    at com.example.app.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.shared.SharedService
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Comment: can you show the class SharedService?

Comment: Here is complete source https://github.com/majerm/spring-component-scan-test

Comment: Don't use the Spring Boot plugin in your shared project, only your app is a spring boot application and thus requires the Spring Boot plugin. The spring boot plugin will repackage and restructure the jar file delivered by the project making it unusable as a regular dependency as it now is a fat jar containing all dependencies,